# Partial sum of Geometric sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, geometric-series

Can someone explain to me how the following summation goes from the left to the right:

$\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1} = \frac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}$.

I have used the formula for a Geometric series. My common ratio is: $(1-p)$. I get the following:

$\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1} = n\cdot\frac{1-(1-p^r)}{1-(1-p)}$.

From here, I simply don't know how to get to $\frac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}$

Comment: For geometric sequence, all you need to know is the first term $b$ and the common ratio $q$.

Comment: i don't think the infinite series should be used here. @mrsamy, how would you get to the final answer i have posted by knowing these terms?

Comment: In your question, $n$ is a constant, which has nothing to do with $i$. The first implication in what you have done is incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? could you elaborate a bit more? I have just used a simple formula for geometric series.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever I wrote an answer. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, $n$ is a constant, which has nothing to do with $i$. The first implication of what you have done is incorrect.

Note that $n(1-p)^{i-1}$ means $n\cdot ((1-p)^{i-1})$, and

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1}=n\sum_{i=1}^{r}(1-p)^{i-1}
$$

all you need to work out is to find a formula for
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r}x^{i-1}
$$
and then set $x=1-p$.

Comment: you are right. I did a mistake with n. But when I use the formula as posted, I don't see how I get to the final result I am looking for.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: that is because you make another mistake; you applied the formula incorrectly. Do you know how to find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^rx^{i-1}$?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever you are almost there: $$\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1} = n\cdot\frac{1-(1-\color{red}{p}^r)}{1-(1-p)}$.$$ $p$ should be $(1-p)$. You just applied the formula incorrectly.

Comment: It's still not the result? see link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n*%28%281-1-%281-p%29%5Er%29%2F%281-1-%281-p%29%29%29

Comment: Where did I applied the formula incorrectly?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: As I said you should first find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^r x^{i-1}$. Do you know how to find that?

Comment: I would need a series for that? wouldn't I? Btw. I just found out that $n\cdot\frac{1-(1-p^r)}{1-(1-p)}$ is in fact $  \frac{n(1-(1-p)^r)}{p}$. Now I just need to figure out how. Simple elimination i guess.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: you are thinking too hard. it is just  $1-(1-p)=p$ in the denominator.

Comment: haha I guess that's what happens when you spend too much time on a thing. Thanks man!

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: no. $1-(1-p)=1-1+\color{red}{p}=p$.

Comment: thanks ! Speaking about the finding of $x^{i-1}$. Why do you have to do that when I just used the geometric formula?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: you are welccome. That is just saving your writing when you write $x$ instead of $1-p$ everywhere.

Comment: but why did you move out the n? Are you supposed to do that when it's a Geometric sequence?

Comment: @GoldenRetriever: you don't *have* to. That simplifies things. Very much like when you calculate $35\cdot 3+35\cdot 3+35\cdot 4$, you would like to factor out $35$ first.

Comment: ah okay. I hope to see you answer my upcoming questions. thanks again. have  a good day.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{r}n(1-p)^{i-1}
&
=n\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(1-p)^i
=[\text{\(r\) terms}]
=n\cdot\frac{1-(1-p)^r}{1-(1-p)}
=\frac{n\bigl(1-(1-p)^r\bigr)}{p}
\end{align*}